# Twig submit form_ajax with parameter PHP

Tags: php, laravel, twig, octobercms, symphony-cms

I am using PHP Laravel and Twig
the php function has a parameter as the following:

```
function onItemApprove($id){
$data = post();
$item = Spot\Shipment\Models\Item::find($id);
....
$item->update();
}
```

the twig has the following code :

```
{{ form_ajax('onItemApprove') }}
```

I want to pass the parameter $id in the twig form_ajax

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/function-form#form_ajax)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add option something like this

```php
{{ form_ajax('onItemApprove', { data: { id: <<some_id>> }}) }}
```

Inside Handler get it from post, not as a parameter

```php
function onItemApprove(){
    $id = post('id');
}
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: I have tried this method, but it is returning error message too few arguments passed 0 passed and 1 expected.

Comment: can you share your code how you are passing `id`

Comment: You need to get the value for 'id' from the POST variables. You can't just specify it as a function parameter for your action handler.

Comment: 1. Twig 
{{ form_ajax('onItemApprove', { data: { id: <<some_id>> }}) }}
2. PHP
function onItemApprove($id){
    $data = post();
    $item = Spot\Shipment\Models\Item::find($id);
   .....
    $item->update()
}